# Action of Lie group on a manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Suppose a Lie group $G$ acts smoothly and properly on a manifold-with-boundary $M$. What can one say about the action of $G$ in relation to the presence of the boundary? For example, does the action induce a (proper) action on $\partial M$ (and hence on $M\backslash\partial M$)?

Comment: A self-diffeomorphism on a manifold with boundary naturally induces a self-diffeomorphism on its boundary, and thus a Lie group action on $M$ also gives a Lie group action on the boundary.

Comment: Thanks! If you write an answer I'll accept.